# Tabla descolocada asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, tablas

Tengo una tabla donde muestro datos de una tabla de `sql server` y al momento de querer ordenarlo, se me muestran de descolocado y chueca.

```
<table id="example3" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fecha)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", @item.Fecha)
      </td>
      <td>
        @item.Nombre
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="@Url.Action(" Descargar ", "ListaDePrecios ", new { id = item.Id })">Descargar</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fecha)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que esté dejando espacios en blanco o tabulaciones en cada `<td>` del `<tbody>`. Intenta dejar el código en una sola línea en lugar de usar saltos de línea e indentación... Algo como esto: `<td>@item.Nombre</td>`

Comment: No creo que sea, ya lo hice y no me funciono